# Как открыть проект, если у него нет .sln файла?

Tags: visual-studio, github

Начал работать с гитхабом. Мне необходимо скачать проект, дабы изучить его. Но на гитхабе есть только папка проекта без sln-файла. Как его открыть?

Comment: ссылочку можно?

Comment: @L.F.C. а что Вы так жёстко с новичком?

Comment: Сделайте `git clone grihub.com/your_project_name`, а затем в VS откройте этот проект. Что-то типа: `open -> exist project`

Comment: @hedgehogues Спасибо)

Comment: @L.F.C. по-моему намного продуктивнее сказать, человеку, что делать, а не уличать его в незнании. Тем более, он спрашивает, как сделать, а не просит сделать за него.

Comment: @L.F.C. VS, очевидно же.

Comment: Клонировав проект, заходишь в новый клонированный репо и работаешь с ним локально, но если в нём не будет `.sln`, ты его не откроешь в таком варианте как был он у предыдущего разработчика. Но в `.cpp` файлах спокойно пороешся и можешь при необходимости доработать их в рамках своего проекта.

Comment: @L.F.C., _если в нём не будет .sln, ты его не откроешь в таком варианте как был он у предыдущего разработчика_ - почему же? основные настройки в проекте

Comment: @Grundy добавь ответ если можешь, я б и для себя хотел лучше разобраться с данным вопросом  и автору ответ будет(я и не утверждаю что я прав, может быть и обратное), хоть и с плюсами пока не работаю

Comment: @L.F.C., а откуда вообще мысль про плюсы?

Comment: @ExistMad, о каком именно проекте идет речь?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90239/discussion-between-grundy-and-l-f-c).